# Jenkins java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-groovy

Some of our jobs that use groovy scripts have started failing today.   It appears the "a" in "apache" is missing and there is a typo in the jfrog download reference.  I suspect this was a long lived typo in the jfrog repo and may have been fixed in the past day or so (I see uploads yesterday), but now is breaking anyone who used it.  Anyone have ideas of how to rectify this?

```
Running as SYSTEM
[EnvInject] - Loading node environment variables.
Building on master in workspace D:\Data\Jenkins\.jenkins\jobs\Emergency Deployment\workspace
Unpacking https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip to D:\Data\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation\Groovy_2.5.3 on Jenkins
FATAL: Failed to install https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip to D:\Data\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation\Groovy_2.5.3
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1836)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnection.java:2943)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getHeaderFieldLong(URLConnection.java:629)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLengthLong(URLConnection.java:501)
    at java.net.URLConnection.getContentLength(URLConnection.java:485)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getContentLength(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:398)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:90)
Caused: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor345.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1885)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1884)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1457)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.getStream(RetryableHttpStream.java:98)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:91)
    at org.jvnet.robust_http_client.RetryableHttpStream.<init>(RetryableHttpStream.java:74)
    at hudson.ProxyConfiguration.getInputStream(ProxyConfiguration.java:330)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:924)
Caused: java.io.IOException: Failed to install https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/pache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip to D:\Data\Jenkins\.jenkins\tools\hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation\Groovy_2.5.3
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:938)
    at hudson.FilePath.installIfNecessaryFrom(FilePath.java:851)
    at hudson.tools.DownloadFromUrlInstaller.performInstallation(DownloadFromUrlInstaller.java:77)
    at hudson.tools.InstallerTranslator.getToolHome(InstallerTranslator.java:69)
    at hudson.tools.ToolLocationNodeProperty.getToolHome(ToolLocationNodeProperty.java:109)
    at hudson.tools.ToolInstallation.translateFor(ToolInstallation.java:206)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyInstallation.forNode(GroovyInstallation.java:73)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.buildCommandLine(Groovy.java:255)
    at hudson.plugins.groovy.Groovy.perform(Groovy.java:79)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:804)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:197)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:163)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:514)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1894)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:428)
Finished: FAILURE
REST API
```

Comment: Was able to update the groovy Installation under "Global Configuration" - Deleted "Install from website" and added extract zip tar to https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/apache-groovy-binary-2.5.3.zip.  This got rid of one error, but still have a failure "[GROOVY WARNING] Groovy executable is NULL, please check your Groovy configuration, trying fallback 'groovy' instead."

Comment: It appears that "something" was corrected "somewhere" and the misspelling was fixed.  No idea where that happened, but this should no longer be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Started hitting this yesterday too. We've also switched to Extract Zip/Tar installer. It's worth noting you probably have to specify the `Subdirectory of extracted archive` setting based on the root dir inside the zip. So for us we used:

```
https://groovy.jfrog.io/artifactory/dist-release-local/groovy-zips/apache-groovy-binary-2.4.9.zip
```

For the Download URL, and the following for the subdir:

```
groovy-2.4.9
```

Comment: ARE YOU KIDDING!!!  It was the darn sub dir.  It is not required and you CAN see if you do not specify it, it does choose one for you.  Makes no sense.  I almost tried that a couple of times, but looking at the logs, I did not think it was an issue.  Thanks - just goes to show...

Comment: AND, now it looks like something was fixed and the old way works again...  I have configured to go to groovy website again and AOK.